# Overwrite customattribute on derived class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, custom-attributes

We have a custom attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomDesignerAttribute: Attribute
```

then we have a base class decorated with this attribute

```
[CustomDesigner(someKey, someValue)]
public class BaseClass
```

then we have a class derived from this one, decorated with same attribute (with same key, different value)

```
[CustomDesigner(someKey, someOtherValue)]
public class ChildClass : BaseClass
```

Is there possibility that ChildClass don't create a duplicate of attribute but overwrite a value for existing key instead (overwrites whole parent attribute)? 
If not, what's the best pattern for getting default value from BaseClass if ChildClass has not defined his own?

Comment: I'm not sure so I'll leave this as a comment: maybe disabling attribute inheritance is a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not possible to override the existing attribute.

Attributes are metadata attached to an object (assembly, class, method, variable and so on) so they always keep this *connection*.

If you want to give a default "behavior" in the base class and override it in some derived classes you have to check all the attributes returned by `GetCustomAttributes()` to use only the most derived one (the first in the list).

Answer (score 3):

use `[AttributeUsage(Inherited=false)]` to prevent the attribute being inherited by the derived class.

Comment: But if BaseClass is shared by many derived classes then he won't have a "default" and he'll must repeat the attribute for each derived class (moreover if the base class is abstract then the attribute itself will be useless)

Comment: no luck with this, no changes if BaseClass is abstract or not

Comment: documentation link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributeusageattribute?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible in the following way:

### 1. Using TypeDescriptor

In your `CustomDesignerAttribute` overwrite `TypeId`:

```
public override object TypeId
{
     get
     {
         return Key.GetHashCode();
      }
 }
```

The base implementation of `TypeId` just uses the attribute type, so no parameters would be involved.

Then u can use 
`TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(typeof(ChildClass)).OfType<CustomDesignerAttribute>()`

`TypeDescriptor` (in contrast to `GetType().GetCustomAttributes`) returns only one attribute based on the same `TypeId`. I tested it and it is the most derived attribute matching the `TypeId` that is returned.

So if your `TypeId` represents the key of your attribute then you can overwrite it on derived classes - when using `TypeDescriptor` to get the attribute! Note that still multiple attributes are possible as long as they differ in their key.

Note: TypeDescriptor also finds dynamically added attributes (added at runtime)

### 2. Using Remove Property

You could add a public `bool Remove { get; set; }` to your `CustomDesignerAttribute`. You can set it to `true` in your derived class while setting the other parameters identical to the base class attribute you want to remove. Then add another attribute with same key but your desired value to your derived class. When getting the attributes you have to evaluate the Remove property in a smart manner. Either using TypeDescriptor as in 1) with `TypeId` e.g. returning `Key.HashCode() + Value.GetHashCode()` or using `GetType().GetCustomAttributes`, in both ways you have to loop through the list of attributes and filter. You have to be aware in what order these lists are, if most derived types first or the other way around.