# Overriding StyleTypedProperty Attribute

Tags: wpf, styles, custom-controls, metadata

I have a CustomControl Deriving from ComboBox

```
  CustomComboBox : ComboBox 
  {}
```

The thing is that ComboBox is decorated with a StyleTypedProperty Attribute :

```
 [StyleTypedProperty(Property = "ItemContainerStyle", StyleTargetType = typeof(ComboBoxItem))]
 public class ComboBox  {}
```

I want to supply a different StyleTargetType , is such a work around possible ?

iv'e also tried defining my own :

```
[StyleTypedProperty(Property = "ItemContainerStyle", StyleTargetType = typeof(CustomComboBoxItem))]
```

that had no effect ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible. Please refer to the following links for more information on this subject:

[Overwrite customattribute on derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787082/overwrite-customattribute-on-derived-class)

[change attributes to a base class property in derived class without overriding](http://forums.asp.net/t/1168349.aspx)

[How to change attribute in derived class](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/541870-how-change-attribute-derived-class)