# Overriding Required ErrorMessage property attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

Are property attribute values able to be overridden? I am able to access the property in the sub class, but MVC is still using the error message in the attribute of the base class.

```
 public class ParentClass
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a name.")]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }

 public class ChildClass : ParentClass
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name.")]
        public override string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry buddy. I do not think this is possible.

See attached article for more information.

[Overwrite customattribute on derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787082/overwrite-customattribute-on-derived-class)