# C# Overriding inherited validation

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following class that all of my entities inherit from:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
#nullable enable

namespace AutomationNavigator.Model.Core
{
    public abstract class NamedEntity : Entity, INamedEntity
    {
        public NamedEntity() : base()
        {
        }

        [MaxLength(100,ErrorMessage ="Name must be 100 characters or less.")]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Name must be at least 3 characters.")]
        [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z0-9_. ]{3,100}$")] // Alphanumeric with Underscore and Dot only
        [Display(Name= "Name")]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The validation on the `Name` field is ok to universally apply except in a specific scenario that I just created where I need to allow special characters is name field in my app. Can I somewhow override/remove the Regex validation? The class I am trying to accomplish this for is:

```
namespace AutomationNavigator.Model.ProcessAssessment
{
    public class ProcessFile: NamedEntity
    {
        [Display(Name = "OrganizationId")]
        public Guid? OrganizationId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
        [Display(Name = "Organization")]
        public Organization? Organization { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "BusinessProcessId")]
        public Guid? BusinessProcessId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BusinessProcessId")]
        [Display(Name = "BusinessProcess")]
        public BusinessProcess? BusinessProcess { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "ProcessDocumentId")]
        public Guid? ProcessDocumentId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProcessDocumentId")]
        [Display(Name = "ProcessDocument")]
        public ProcessDocument? ProcessDocument { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "ProcessFileStatusLookupId")]
        public Guid? ProcessFileStatusLookupId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProcessFileStatusLookupId")]
        [Display(Name = "LookupValue")]
        public LookupValue? LookupValue { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "BlobId")]
        public Guid? BlobId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BlobId")]
        [Display(Name = "Blob")]
        public Blob? Blob { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "SizeInBytes")]
        public double? SizeInBytes { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Version")]
        public double? Version { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(500, ErrorMessage = "Description must be 500 characters or less.")]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string? Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787082/overwrite-customattribute-on-derived-class

Comment: I would expect that this will work: make the Name virtual in the abstract class and overwrite it in your exception case.

Comment: @MKR that's for class attributes. I think it's possible for method attributes

Comment: @Julian You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual properties are a good way of allowing descendents to customise behaviour.

I would make the Name property virtual in the abstract class and override it in the derived specific class where you need to change the validation.

In the abstract class:

```
[MaxLength(100,ErrorMessage ="Name must be 100 characters or less.")]
[Required]
[MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Name must be at least 3 characters.")]
[RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z0-9_. ]{3,100}$")]
[Display(Name= "Name")]
public virtual string? Name { get; set; }
```

In the derived class:

```
public class ProcessFile: NamedEntity
{    
   public override string? Name { get; set;} 
}
```

You can also make the base class' name directly available for the derived class and validate it. Something like:

```
public abstract class NamedEntity
{
    protected string name;

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            //validation, if any
        }
    }

    public NamedEntity()
    {
        name = "";
    }

}

public class ProcessFile: NamedEntity
{

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return base.Name; }

        set { base.Name = // new validation; }
    }

    public ProcessFile()
        : base()
    {
        base.Name = "";        
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Hello Pedro. I first want to say thank you for your thorough answer. I am going to make the prop virtual and then override it in the derived class. That is genius and I did not know you could do that with properties.I thought that was reserved for methods only. Learn something new everyday. However, I really do not understand what you are doing in the second option you gave me. Can you elaborate a little more on what you are doing with the getters and setters in each class? Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, Dean. Thanks. 
The getters and setters from the base class are just for encapsulation (check this article: https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_properties.asp). In the derived class, the setter could be like set { base.Name = value; } (maybe with a new validation, if desired), where the value keyword is the value defined by the client. Note that, by doing so, we are also overriding the value from base class. The following article has a similar example (base class is not an abstract class, though):
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value